# make -j (jobs) option ignored when building Android (defaulting to all cores)

Tags: android, build, compilation, ninja

I'm building Android-x86 (the `nougat-x86` branch) with this sequence of commands:

```bsh
repo init -u git://git.osdn.net/gitroot/android-x86/manifest -b nougat-x86

repo sync --no-tags --no-clone-bundle

virtualenv2 venv

. venv/bin/activate

. build/envsetup.sh

lunch android_x86_64-userdebug

export ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS="-Xmx4g -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
export JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENT=$ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS
export SERVER_NB_COMPILE=1
export USE_CCACHE=1

LANG=C LC_ALL=C make -j2 iso_img
```

Note how I'm specifying two make jobs with option `-j2` at the last line.

Regardless, the build is actually spawning 8 processes of `clang` / `clang++` / `javac` and whatever else.

This causes the build to fail:

> GC overhead limit exceeded
>   Try increasing heap size with java option '-Xmx'
>   Warning: This may have produced partial or corrupted output.
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>   make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
>
> make failed to build some targets

How to enforce the `-j2` option to make sure my CPU and RAM are not maxed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause: The JACK server is evil.

The following solves the out-of-ram problem:

```sh
./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin kill-server
rm -rf ~/.jack*    
export ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS="-Xmx4g -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
export SERVER_NB_COMPILE=2
export JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENT=$ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS
./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.*.ALPHA.jar
./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server
```

Many thanks to [the FUCK JACK! project](https://github.com/mikecriggs/fuckjack). Modified script with changes from [issue #2](https://github.com/mikecriggs/fuckjack/issues/2) and [PR 5](https://github.com/mikecriggs/fuckjack/pull/5).

---

What is not immediately obvious is that the build was failing not because the MACHINE has run out of memory, but because the JACK server has. Indeed, the error message says...

> Try **increasing** heap size with java option '-Xmx'

(emphasis mine).

This webpage at http://www.2net.co.uk/blog/jack-server.html explains...

> (...) let’s look at the default heap size on two different machines.
>   The default heap size scales according to the total amount of memory
>   fitted, ignoring the swap space. On a 16 GiB machine, it is over 3
>   GiB:
>
> ```sh
> $ java -XshowSettings 2>&1  | grep Heap
>     Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 3.47G
> ```
>
> But, on an 8 GiB machine, it is less than 2 GiB:
>
> ```sh
> $ java -XshowSettings 2>&1  | grep Heap
>     Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 1.71G
> ```
>
> It turns out that jack-server needs about 3 GiB to build a typical
>   AOSP Nougat target, and so it fails if the machine doesn’t have enough
>   RAM. Increasing the swap space makes no difference.

Alright. So, using the above commands I was able to increase the heap size to 4GiB and got to compile without errors.

---

Now...

### How to enforce the -j2 option to make sure my CPU and RAM are not maxed out?

The page at (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/sdk/+/master/tools/README-jack-server.md) says

> **config.properties file**
>
> It contains Jack server configuration properties. Modifications to
>   those settings are taken into account after restarting the server.
>   Description with default values follows:
>
> `jack.server.max-service=<number>` Maximum number of simultaneous Jack
>   tasks. Default is 4.
>
> (...)
>
> **If your computer becomes unresponsive during compilation:**
>
> You can improve the situation by reducing the number of jack
>   simultaneous compilations by editing your
>   `$HOME/.jack-server/config.properties` and changing
>   jack.server.max-service to a lower value and then restarting the
>   server.

### TL;DR:

`jack.server.max-service=2` in `$HOME/.jack-server/config.properties` and restart the JACK server.